# Jasper Reports PDF page width

Tags: pdf, jasper-reports

I'm using Jasper Reports to generate a PDF report. Here, I need to have a PDF of width 600 for first page and width of 1200 for second page. I know that we can set page width and height for the whole document, but is it possible to set width and height for each page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JasperPrint objects does not support mixed page formats.
However, I think, there are following work-arounds.

1) You can switch the entire report orientation to Landscape.

2) The other one given [here](http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/513721/landscape-and-portrait-layout-same-report).